# Bind property to ObjectProperty's property

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to make a line that points to a node in a property:

```
ObjectProperty<Node> pointedToNode = new SimpleObjectProperty();
```

I want a line to point to it like so:

```
line.endXProperty().bind(pointedToNode.get().layoutXProperty());
```

The problem with this is when `pointedToNode` changes, the binded value (`pointedToNode.get()`) has changed, and the `layoutXProperty()` is no longer valid.

I also need the line to be invisible if the value of `pointedToNode` is null.

I tried some custom double bindings with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the plain API:

```
ChangeListener<Number> xListener = (obs, oldX, newX) -> 
    line.setEndX(newX.doubleValue());
pointedToNode.addListener((obs, oldNode, newNode) -> {
    if (oldNode != null) {
        oldNode.layoutXProperty().removeListener(xListener);
    }
    if (newNode != null) {
        newNode.layoutXProperty().addListener(listener);
    }
});
```

Or, using the [EasyBind](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind) framework:

```
line.endXProperty().bind(
    EasyBind.select(pointedToNode)
    .selectObject(Node::layoutXProperty)
    .orElse(-1)); // value if pointedToNode is null
```

You can try using the `Bindings.select` (standard) API, which looks a bit like EasyBind but has several disadvantages: it doesn't deal elegantly with `null` values in the "chain" (i.e. if `pointedToNode.get()` is `null`); it is not typesafe; and it is prone to premature garbage collection.

```
line.endXProperty().bind(Bindings.selectDouble(pointedToNode, "layoutX"));
```

I recommend the EasyBind approach, or, if you don't want to use a third-party library for some reason, just use the "by hand" listener approach in the first code block.

For visibility, just do

```
line.visibleProperty().bind(pointedToNode.isNull());
```